# OpenCV link problem

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli, linker, opencv

HI

I switched from visual studio 2008 to 2010,
now I have problem linking my lib files from opencv 1.1

I've added required libs and .h files.
but I get following error:

"Error  53  error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'cv.lib.obj' C:\Users..\SOLOUTION_NAME\PROJECT_NAME\LINK"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really a solution to linking issues but OpenCV is now in version 2.1 in release thanks to work by [WillowGarage](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/). The new builds use CMake based system and are much friendlier. Why don't you make a switch to a more up-to-date version. It offers many more functions especially in feature recognition using SIFT/HOG etc.

Comment: Agreed. You should switch to OpenCV 2.1. Most functions in OpenCV 1.1 still works just fine linking and building against OpenCV 2.1